# Is there a <label> tag in react native?

Tags: react-native, accessibility

I'm making a form in React native.
A field in this form in (non-native) React would be like this:

```
<div>
  <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lastName" />
</div>
```

Or in plain `html`:

```
<div>
  <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lastName">
</div>
```

I find the label tag important for accessibility reasons.
Every tutorial I found uses only placeholders and I couldn't find any reference for `<label>` in the react native documentation.
The placeholder disappears as the user starts typing, which makes the page less accessible.

The `<label>` tag also has the advantage of directing focus to the input when clicked.
This means a click on `<label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name:</label>` prompts the user to input in the field `<input type="text" id="lastName" />`.

For this reason using `<Text>` tag as a `<label>` is not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the closest possible approach in terms of semantics and accessibility would be:

```
<View>
  <Text aria-label="Label for Username" nativeID="labelUsername">Username</Text>
  <TextInput aria-label="input" aria-labelledby="labelUsername" />
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<View>` as your `<div>` and `<Text>` as your `<label>`.

`<input>` is `<TextInput>`

then you just have to style the elements to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, that would be an esthetic solution. However, in html the `<label>` tag also works as a link to the input and the app reacts the same way whether you click on the label or the input. In your example when I click on the `<Text>` tag nothing happens.

Comment: You can wrap the Text in a TouchableOpacity to make it clickable check this out: https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity

Comment: Thank you that could be a work around. And if you need to answer my question in one word would that be "No"? Because there's no equivalent in react-native?

Comment: The way you would do it in RN is with TouchableOpacity. So there is no real equivalent to label - but there might be some 3rd library packages from the community to do that. However I would just stick to TouchableOpacity in this case since it gets used a lot to make "everything" clickable :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the best practice would be to wait until react-native introduces an equivalent to the <label> tag. Although your answer is helpful, it doesn't fully solves the problem.